# Image size increases after processing in Graphics2D

Tags: java, graphics2d

The following code results an image of higher size. My original image 200x200 was 6 KB. After the this I got an out put of 100KB.

When I resupply the output as input again, it is not changing the size

```
    File imageFile = "path to image"
    BufferedImage subImage= ImageIO.read(new FileInputStream(imageFile));
    BufferedImage dest = new BufferedImage(200, 200, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    Graphics2D g2 = dest.createGraphics();
    g2.drawImage(subImage, 0, 0, 200, 200, null);
    g2.dispose();
    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ImageIO.write(dest, "png", out);
```

Comment: can you add the code where you read in the mage and when you saved it again? If the original file was a JPG and you saved it as something else, there is no surprise in the change of the file size.

Comment: @Lothar. Yes the original image was JPG. I have updated the code now.

Answer (score 0):

Image size varies depending on the *format*, *compression* and *channels* chosen.

PNG usually uses more size because it offers an *alpha channel* (which you used here) and does *lossless compression*, compared to JPEG.

Try chosing `"JPEG"` when writing the image, and check if the size and quality suits your needs better.